# Just started learning Logic and dont understand, M&N->E

Tags: logic

[image: Here is my problem,]
 so as i learned implication is only true when the input is:$0\to1, 1\to1, 0\to0$,
and false when, $1\to0$

but in this picture, at line 5. 6. the input is $1\to0$ but its true and when it both true at the next line its false.

Answer (score 2):

In lines 5 and 6, $M $ is true, $N $  is false, so $M \land N $ is false and the implication is true no matter what $E $ is (both $0\Rightarrow 0$ and $0\Rightarrow 1$ are $1$).

In lines 7, 8, both $M $ and $ N $ are true, so the implication is true only if $E $ is true (line 8: $1\Rightarrow 1$) but not when $E $ is false (line 7: $1\Rightarrow 0$).

**NB**: In logic, we first calculate $\land $ and $\lor $ and then $\Rightarrow $, the same as we first multiply and then add in arithmetic.

---

Addendum: Let's rewrite the table to make it clearer which is being connected to what.

$$\def\To{\mathop{\Rightarrow}}
\begin{array}{|c:c:c|c:c|c|cc|}\hline
M & N & E & M{\wedge}N & E & (M{\wedge}N){\To}E \\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 &  0        & 0 & \hspace{6ex} 1 \\ \hdashline
0 & 0 & 1 &  0        & 1 & \hspace{6ex} 1 \\ \hdashline
0 & 1 & 0 &  0        & 0 & \hspace{6ex} 1 \\ \hdashline
0 & 1 & 1 &  0        & 1 & \hspace{6ex} 1 \\ \hdashline
1 & 0 & 0 &  0        & 0 & \hspace{6ex} 1 \\ \hdashline
1 & 0 & 1 &  0        & 1 & \hspace{6ex} 1 \\ \hdashline
1 & 1 & 0 &  1        & 0 & \hspace{6ex} 0 &\star\\ \hdashline
1 & 1 & 1 &  1        & 1 & \hspace{6ex} 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$